# Change attribute table appearance to show only features visible in map

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Working with big WFS it can take forever to open the tables. Is it possible to choose to show only features visible in map before opening it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CTRL + F6 to open the table with only the visible features, Shift + F6 to open only the selected features.

https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=f6#introducing-the-attribute-table-interface